# ng-dynamic-forms group sections

Tags: angular, typescript

Well, I run into following problem. To show group section header I am using approach from documentation. It works fine if known modelId is put in the HTML template. But if modelId is unknown (approach below) during compilation it does not work, section header is not shown. So I see header for request (as it is always named that way) but when I add subsections to parent group it does not work with approach bellow. I suppose problem could be solved by compiling template at runtime but I want to check if there is some out of box solution that I am not aware of. Also if I put subsections id for subsection that I know modelId it works, but because I can't know modelId in front I need to dynamically create sections headers.

```
<ng-template modelId="request" let-id="legend" align="START">
                    <div class="bg-light mt-3 header">
                        <span class="d-inline-block p-2">{{ id }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <ng-template *ngFor="let name of subsectionNames[index]" [modelId]="name" let-id="legend" align="START">
                        <div class="bg-light mt-3 header">
                            <span class="d-inline-block p-2">{{ id }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </ng-template>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need titles for the groups. If I know id of modelId at the compile time, it works. Like for "request" from my example. I need the same for the case when modelId is known only at runtime. I tried to solve it with a ngFor but it does not work. I mean forms works (controls are in the form) except those groups don't have subtitle. So I have visual problem to divide groups with some title.

Comment: So my question is in general could I use this `<ng-template modelId="request" let-id="legend" align="START">
     <div class="bg-light mt-3 header">
      <span class="d-inline-block p-2">{{ id }}</span>
     </div>
    </ng-template>` dynamic way if modelId is not known at compile time?

Comment: I just realized even with ngFor works, but it has some issues, so I am investigating what is happening. Sometimes header part for group shows and sometimes don't.

Comment: Solution for my problem was to collect all possible group ids in all pages and use them in ngFor for any page.